# Can't Update Database from ASP.NET Webform

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, sql-update

I can't get an ASP.NET webform to update a database. I'm trying to edit an existing record in the database. The webform populates the data from the record into the form. The user then changes data and updates the record in the database when the form is submitted.

The problem is that nothing is changed in the database when a modified form is submitted. What am I doing wrong here? The SQL works in MSSQL Management Studio.

Thanks.

```
private void SaveToDatabase ()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (_connectionString_Bluebook))
    {
        conn.Open ();

        string sql = @"update Companies

                            set CompanyName=@CompanyName, AccountNo=@AccountNo

                            where AccountNo=" + _accountNo;

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sql, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter ("@CompanyName", TextBox_CompanyName.Text));
            command.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter ("@AccountNo", TextBox_Account.Text));

            command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
        }

        conn.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `_accountNo` and see if it is what you are expecting? Where is that value set?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are not re-populating on postback?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parameter for the original account number to your query. The example below uses strongly-typed parameters for security and performance, taking a guess at your actual SQL data types and column lengths, which you should change to your actual definitions.

```
private void SaveToDatabase()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString_Bluebook))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string sql = @"update dbo.Companies

                    set CompanyName=@CompanyName, AccountNo=@AccountNo

                    where AccountNo=@OriginalAccountNo;
                    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('Account number %s not found',16,1,@OriginalAccountNo)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyName",SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = TextBox_CompanyName.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccountNo", SqlDbType.Char, 10).Value = TextBox_Account.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalAccountNo", SqlDbType.Char, 10).Value = _accountNo;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

If the row is still not updated as expected, make sure `_accountNo` contains the proper value.

**EDIT:**

I added a `RAISERROR` statement to the SQL batch to facilitate this, which you could leave in the code if the not found condition should never occur.

Answer (score -1):

If the SQL Params are not working, then try this way:

```
comm = new SqlCommand("update student_detail set s_name= '" + txtname.Text + "', age= "+txtage.Text+" , course=' " + txtcourse.Text + "' where roll_no = " + txtrn.Text + " ", conn);
```

2. Try to place the debugger and provide the exact error of the compiler

Comment: Although the debugger is a good suggestion, I down voted because changing a parameterized query to string concatenation from untrusted user input is really a bad idea.

Comment: Hi Gal, the suggestion of changing to concat is just to find out whether the issue is with query or with the sql connection . Any how i never feel bad about down vote :) , as this is a scope of improvement .

Comment: In that case, I think it would be best to mention that in your answer so that it won't be left in the production code. I've had my share of down votes :-)